# jQuery set class active with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu like :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#one">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#two">two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#three">three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And on my page, multiple anchor like :

```
<a id="two" target="_blank"></a>
```

or

```
<a id="one" target="_blank"></a>
```

I'm looking for a way to set an active class to my menu when i scroll to an anchor (with click or mouse scroll).

For example if i scroll to my anchor `id="two"` i need to set active my `li #two`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you're open to the use of plugins - scrollspy is pretty nice: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Comment: I prefer without plugin

Comment: How are you "*scrolling to*" these elements? Manually scrolling with the mouse/scroll bars, or clicking a link? Or both?

Comment: with the mouse, scroll bar or click on the menu

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, add your anchors some class, for example `section` and try this:

```
$('.section').hover(function() {
  var anchor = $(this).attr('id');

    $('a[href="#'+anchor+'"]').addClass('active');

}, function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/MwMWoK

Comment: I can't add a class to my anchors

Comment: Then perhaps try to target them by selector, but it's kinda dangerous. Oh, and my solution requires jQuery, if that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a.scroll-to");
console.log(links[1]);
for (var i = links.length -1; i>=0; i--)
{        
         //click event
         links[i].onclick= someHandlerFunction;
         //hover event
    links[i].onmouseover= someHandlerFunction;
}
var liActive = undefined;
function someHandlerFunction(event) {
    if (liActive != undefined) liActive.setAttribute("class", "");
    liActive = event.target.parentNode;
    liActive.setAttribute("class", "active");
    return false;
}
```

```css
.menu{
     background-color: #00ff00;
}
.menu li.active{
     background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#one">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#two">two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="scroll-to" href="#three">three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Voila (add and remove class in the same time), it's a but it's a bit redundant to add active class at click and hover.

Comment: i don't understand, i need to set an active class when i scroll to an element.. With your code is just on click and hover in the menu

Comment: What else is requiered to do?